# Reading/writing only needed data to/from a large data file to minimize memory footprint

Tags: c++, qt, large-files

I'm currently brainstorming a financial program that will deal with (over time) fairly large amounts of data. It will be a C++/Qt GUI app.

I figure reading all the data into memory at runtime is out of the question because given enough data, it might hog too much memory.

I'm trying to come up with a way to read into memory only what I need, for example, if I have an account displayed, only the data that is actually being displayed (and anything else that is absolutely necessary). That way the memory footprint could remain small even if the data file is 4gb or so.

I thought about some sort of searching function that would slowly read the file line by line and find a 'tag' or something identifying the specific data I want, and then load that, but considering this could theoretically happen every time there's a gui update that seems like a terrible way to go.

Essentially I want to be able to efficiently locate specific data in a file, read only that into memory, and possibly change it and write it back without reading and writing the whole file every time. I'm not an experienced programmer and my googling for ideas hasn't been very successful.

Edit: I should probably mention I intend to use Qt's fancy QDataStream related classes to store the data. In other words the file will likely be binary and not easily searchable line by line like a text file.

Comment: Will the data stored in your file essentially be a large number of records sharing a similar structure ? Is a key/value (where value is a complex structure) an over simplification ?

Comment: *ahem* considering what your planning to do, one might want to look into using a relational database of some sort, like postgres

Comment: you may also consider (older free version) of Berkeley DB or mongoDB (which is quite possibly exactly what you want)

Comment: The data will be _fairly_ similar structures with a large number of records. Each record will have a bunch of data types and data associated with it. What makes it more interesting though is the file will have other data as well that is not just a bunch of similar records.

I thought about using mysql or similar to make it easy - and probably will add support for a database backend eventually - but since I'm writing this program for fun as a learning experience I'd like to figure out how to efficiently use a data file.

Comment: Another thought I had was to generate some sort of index of records (id/file location pairs) or something along those lines, but then I'd have to figure out how to organize the "blocks" of data and make sure they are big enough to store whatever they might contain, and that seems a bit complicated.

Comment: You seem to reinventing a database, one wonders why? Is this a single user application or a server? Is theregoing to be one file for accounts one for transactions, etc. This can be done, not sure it should be though. Even the simpler scenarios are a hefty chew for someone experienced with this sort of thing. Even my famously large ego would be aving second thoughts

Comment: Agree wtih @Tony.... this might not be the best way of having "fun" while learning to use files as a substitute for a database, especially with data size expected to be in the GB range...

Comment: A learning experience it will be :D . I'd recommend with looking at some of the old style hierarchical database stuff for inspiration. If you are planning on multi user though, got to be in from the start retro fitting will be a total rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Okay based on your comments.

Start simple. Forget about your fiscal application for now, except as background. So suitable example for your file system

One data type e.g accounts.
Start with fixed width columns giving you a fixed width record.

One file for data
Have another file for the index of account number

Do Insert, Update and Delete, you'll learn a lot.

For instance.
Delete, you could find the index and the data, move them out and rebuild both files.

You could have a an internal field on the account record, that indicated it had been deleted, set that in data, and just remove the index. The latter is also rewrite the entire file though. You could put the delete flag in the index file instead...
When inserting do you want to append, do you want to find a deleted record and reuse that slot?

Is your index just going to be a straight list of accounts and position, or dovyouvwant to hash it, use a tree. You could spend a weeks if not months just looking at indexing strategies alone.

Happy learning anyway. It will be interesting to help with your future questions.

Comment: Thanks. Lots to think about. I may indeed be biting off more than I can chew at the moment... a database would certainly seem to be the solution to the overall need, but I'll keep pondering :) I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, just trying to learn how "real" programmers do it!

Comment: we borrow stuff that already works. :D You would learn a lot by doing this, but you will learn a lot using a dbms as well.